# FLUTTER - Put label and hint inside a textformfield, add fillColor and circular borders

Tags: flutter

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkvDQ.png)
I wish to make a textFormField like its in the image.

- The hint and label must be aligned like they are in the image.
  However, there are a few changes.
  First - There should be a background color
  Second - No border colors to be added, ONLY shape (Circular border) should change.

These designs remain the same on onFocus and other states.

I tried to do them altogether but the label keeps on moving at the border. Here is my code which implements everything except having circular border.

Please tell me how to go about it.

```
TextFormField(
      controller: widget.textController,
      obscureText: widget.obscure,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return widget.errorMessage;
        }
        return null;
      },
      cursorColor: hintColor,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: textfieldFilledColor,
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        hintText: widget.hint,
        labelText: widget.label,
        border: InputBorder.none,
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter TextFormField hint label and cursor position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490441/flutter-textformfield-hint-label-and-cursor-position)

Comment: No, it does not. If there is an error then, the error text is being displayed inside that container only. The container expands to display it. However, I want it to be displayed outside of the container.